# Nested Material UI Dialog with Table not rendering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I have a component that renders a fullscreened `<Dialog>` with a `<Table>`.

Every row in this `<Table>` contains a `<TableCell>`, which contains a `<Button>` component.

When pressed, another, not fullscreened `<Dialog>` containing a `<Table>` should pop up and show what the object in the main `<Table`> contains.

**Something like this:**

**---Basket---Total---Products----Date-----**

-------A---------3------------[1]------someDate-- // `[1]` being the button

`onClick()` of `[1]` triggers the smaller `<Dialog>`

**---Name---Price---Quantity---**

----Prod-------3----------1-------  // Nested `<Dialog>`

Now, I have a method that just parses the date I get from the backend into the **Date** column in the main `<Table>`.

Funnily, if I press the `<Button>` for the second, smaller `<Dialog>`, the method gets called again, everything freezes for 5 seconds and a bunch of windows pop up over each other.

I have my `open` variable in the state, so I thought that the whole thing gets rerenderer when I toggle it. Which would make sense.

I tried using `<Modal>` which would actually be a better option, but it just crashes Chrome. Screen becomes black with parallel lines across.

So, basically, I'm doing two loops in the `<Dialog>` component.

**Here's the code using `<Dialog>`:**

```
<Dialog
    open={this.props.loadBasketsWindowOpen}
    transition={Transition}
    keepMounted
    onClose={this.handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
    fullScreen
    >
    <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">
       <p style={centerDiv}>{"Baskets: "}{this.props.openBaskets.length}</p>
       <hr style={horizontalLineStyle}/>
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
        <div style={centerDiv}>
            <Table>
               <TableHead>
                   <TableRow>
                       <TableCell style={tableTextStyle}>User</TableCell>
                       <TableCell style={tableTextStyle}>Total</TableCell>
                       <TableCell style=tableTextStyle}>Products</TableCell>
                       <TableCell style={tableTextStyle}>Date</TableCell>
                       <TableCell></TableCell>
                   </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                   {this.props.baskets !== undefined ? 
                     this.props.baskets.map(basket => {
                     return(
                        <TableRow key={basket.id}>
                        <TableCell style={tableTextStyle}>
                            {basket.user}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell style={tableTextStyle}>
                            €{basket.total}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell style={tableTextStyle}>
                           <Button onClick={this.onToggle}>                                                          
                            {basket.posBasketItems.length}
                              <Dialog
                                open={this.state.innerTableWindowOpen}
                                onClose={this.handleClose}
                                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
                                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide- 
                                description"
                              >
                                <DialogTitle>
                                  <p style={centerDiv}>
                                     {"Cart: "} 
                                     {basket.length} Products
                                  </p>
                                  <hr style={horizontalLineStyle}/>
                                </DialogTitle>
                                <DialogContent>
                                  <Table>                                                  
                                    <TableHead>                           
                                       <TableRow>                                                                           
                                          <TableCell>
                                             Name
                                          </TableCell>
                                          <TableCell>
                                             Price
                                          </TableCell>
                                          <TableCell>
                                             Quantity
                                          </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>                        
                                     </TableHead>                              
                                  <TableBody>                               
                                    {basket.items.map(item => {                                  
                                       return (                                
                                         <TableRow key={item.id}>  

                                            <TableCell>
                                              {item.name} 
                                            </TableCell>

                                            <TableCell>
                                              {item.price}
                                            </TableCell>

                                            <TableCell>
                                              {item.quantity}
                                            </TableCell>

                                          </TableRow>

                                        );
                                     })}                          
                                   </TableBody>
                                  </Table>
                                </DialogContent>
                              </Dialog>
                            </Button>
                           </TableCell>

                           <TableCell>
                             {this.parseDate(basket.date)} 
                           </TableCell>

                           <TableCell>
                             <Button 
                              onClick={()=>this.setToCurrentBasket(basket)}
                             >
                             <ADD_TO_SHOPPING_CART />
                             </Button>
                           </TableCell>
                         </TableRow>
                       );
                }) : ''}
              </TableBody>
             </Table>
           </div>
          </DialogContent>
         <DialogActions>
            <div>
               <MuiThemeProvider theme={cancelButtonTheme}>
                  <Button 
                     variant="raised" 
                     onClick={this.closeOpenBasketsWindow} 
                     color="secondary"
                  >
                     CANCEL
                  </Button>
               </MuiThemeProvider>
            </div>
         </DialogActions>
     </Dialog>
```

**Here's `onToggle()` and the state**

```
state = {
   innerTableWindowOpen: false
};

onToggle = () => {
   this.setState({
      innerTableWindowOpen: !this.state.innerTableWindowOpen
   });
}
```

I would appreciate any idea to fix this with `<Dialog>` or `<Modal>` or even something similar.

The idea is to have a short **preview** of what's in the basket before choosing one.

Thanks!

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: I would, but it only has Material UI 0.20... Nevermind, I just used npm to get the right version.

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wtbyjw) it is. I don't know why it's not rendering, but I tried to add everything in a way as I get it from the backend.

Comment: There's too many errors there to look at. Can you get it working and then send it to me please?